# Set program's directory as the initial directory of JavaFX FileChooser

Tags: java, javafx, path, filechooser

I am using JavaFX. I would like to start a `FileChooser` from the directory of the program, the initial repository should therefore be that of the program.

Here is my `FileChooser` declaration:

```
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
chooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
new ExtensionFilter("Text Files", "*.txt"),
new ExtensionFilter("All Files", "*.*"));
chooser.setTitle("Choisir un fichier");
file = chooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
```

How can I do that?

Comment: this question is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318974/javafx-filechooser-initial-directory).  You can also check [the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html). The method you are looking for is setInitialDirectory(File value).

Comment: It was not. The answer you're giving tells how to set the user's directory as the initial directory. That's not my question.

Comment: What does "the directory of the program" mean?

Comment: The directory where the executable program file reside.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file ???

Comment: Easy as hell. I thougth you could guess. The dir is "."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current dir is ".". Here is how you can do that:

```
FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
String currentPath = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString();
chooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(currentPath));
chooser.showOpenDialog(new Stage());
```

Edit: the Stage or javafx Node you should be passing to the FileChooser is the one you want to be its parent.